# Jquery double click event after appending element to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone, agiletoolkit

I'm using agile toolkit, a framework that generates javascript code from PHP. I have a div element (I'll call it "top-element") that contains some other div elements, some buttons.
I want to move the "top-element" to another element, to change it's parent.

I tried something like:

```
$('#top-element').appendTo($('#new-parent'));
```

But the problem is that the "top-element" have some childrens that have click events, some buttons. After I append the "top-element" to a new element (after changing it's parent), the click events are triggered twice.

I tried to clone the element and append the cloned element to the new parent:

```
var cloned_top_element = $('#top-element').clone(true);
cloned_top_element.appendTo($('#new-parent'));
```

I got the same problem, the click event on "top-element" childrens was called twice.

The way to prevent double click is to use:

```
unbind('click') or off('click')
```

I tried something like:

```
$('#new-parent').find('.children-class').unbind('dblclick').unbind('click');
```

But still no results.

The binding for child buttons is like this:

```
$('.children-class').bind('click',function(ev){ ev.preventDefault();ev.stopPropagation(); other stuff });
```

The bind function appears only once. There aren't duplicates in the js code.

Any ideas? Anticipated thanks.

Comment: How are you binding the click event in the first place?

Comment: can you replicate this error in a jsfiddle?

Comment: No, because I have a framework and there's a lot of custom code.

Comment: can you at least provide the html

Comment: no, because it's a lot of code implied

Comment: You say it "appears" once - do you also mean that it is only "called" once?

Comment: yes, it's called only once. Regarding "bind" this is not deprecated, but "As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated.". We're not using jquery 3.0..

Comment: I didn't say deprecated, I said replaced.  :)

Comment: The framework generated bind by default. I personally use "on"..but "bind" should also work good

Comment: You'll need to try to recreate the problem in new code.  There's too much "other" code that could be causing the problem, such as the "framework" and your html structure.  If you can't recreate this using a simple jsfiddle (couple of divs, and appendTo) then it *must* be something in that hidden code which we cannot see, therefore cannot help you with.  This might help [mcve]

Comment: Good point, but I created this question with the hope that maybe someone else had the same problem in the past.

Comment: I also tried to replace the initial bind('click') event with unbind('click').bind('click') , but still no changes. This should do the stuff, but in my case is not working

Comment: Here's a fiddle with all the information you've provided: https://jsfiddle.net/hefaa8ky/  I recommend updating the question title to include the framework (hidden in a comment) and maybe add a tag (if there is one) for that framework.   It's possible it's a known issue with the framework, but, as the question stands, it's not reproducible.

Comment: You're right. I guess this problem is framework-related.

Comment: The ugly thing is that the element bind event appears only once in the page's js source code, so there shouldn't be two triggers. I'll check all his parents, maybe there's a bug.

Comment: Have you tried using detach() and then appendTo() ?

Comment: Yes, but it's working similar to clone. It still triggers two clicks. It's a page related js issue, it happens only on one page, it's not a general js issue.

Comment: would have helped, but was only following [atk4] tag not [agiletoolkit]. Will follow both now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `true` in the [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function `.clone();` this will not copy the  event handlers

Comment: I tried this also. Still two triggers for the click event.

Comment: No, because I have a framework and there's a lot of custom code. The js  regarding click events is generated by the framework. But is valid js code.

Comment: it is called: agile toolkit

Comment: This is why I've accepted your answer: It was a framework specific issue. In the end, the clone() followed by initial element hide and an append of the cloned element to the new parent solved the problem. Thanks.